# GETDATE() in a T-SQL Job Step Command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, jobs

I can't seem to get the GETDATE() syntax to work in a Job Step of type Transact-Sql Script. I put in the command as:

```
execute insertMostRecentUpdate 
@Data='Data', 
@Date=GETDATE()-1
```

But I get an "incorrect syntax near ')'" error when parsing or trying to run it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
SET @date = GETDATE()-1;

execute insertMostRecentUpdate 
@Data='Data', 
@Date=@date;
```

You cannot use `GETDATE()` as inline-function while calling a procedure.

Comment: In addition to Florian: Be careful that getdate()-1 does not mean yesterday (as getdate has a time component as well)

Comment: Thanks Flo! Learn something new every day. I'm a little annoyed that none of my googling turned this up :)

Comment: @C Bauer Very welcome :-); and please also notice @Tobiasopdenbrouw's very important information. As a second extension: With SS2k8 we all should start using DATETIME2 and SYSDATETIME() and get rid of DATETIME and GETDATE().

Comment: GETDATE()-1 is yesterday, that's what I'm using it for :D In 2k8 they are phasing out GETDATE() and DATETIME? DATETIME2 is a bit ugly :/

Comment: DATETIME (and all related functions) does have a bug. It's imprecise with milliseconds that can cause issues. Try this:

SELECT CAST('2010-01-01 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME), CAST('2010-01-01 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME2);

DATETIME2 is much more precise (100ns)

Comment: @CBauer - no, Getdate()-1 is a specific date AND time (yesterday), and not the whole period that is 'yesterday'. As you're inserting, you're probably not bothered by it, but careful when selecting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this,

```
declare @date date
set @date = GETDATE()-1

exec insertMostRecentUpdate 'data',@date
```

Suprise me when i ran, thought i should compile, but I think its because you are passing a function into your proc